# Approximation of measured-valued function by continuous functions

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, approximation-theory

For each $x\in R^d$, let $\nu(x,dz)$ be a L\'evy measure, i.e.,
$$
\int_{R^d}(|z|^2\wedge1)\nu(x,dz)<\infty.
$$
Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $R^d$ such that
$$
\int_{R^d}\int_{R^d}(|z|^2\wedge1)\nu(x,dz)\mu(dx)<\infty.
$$
Can we find  a sequence of $\nu_n(x,dz)$ such that
$$
x\to\int_{R^d}(|z|^2\wedge1)\nu_n(x,dz)
$$
is continuous and
$$
\int_{R^d}\left|\int_{R^d}(|z|^2\wedge1)\nu(x,dz)-\int_{R^d}(|z|^2\wedge1)\nu_n(x,dz)\right|\mu(dx)\to0
$$
as $n\to\infty$ ??